# ERROR_CACHE_MISS when passing value from PHP to bash

Tags: php, bash

I am trying to pass some values from a PHP file to a BASH script. I am getting a ERROR CACHE_MISS response.
The variable 'coretown' holes the value 'Houston, TX'. It must be in that format for the bash script to work.

Results  of a test to prove the variables are correct

```
WorkString531cdf6b8b3451.99781853 OutString531cdf6b8b3451.99781853 Houston, TX
```

Execute the bash script.

```
$errorTrap=shell_exec("./Find-Town.sh $workPath $outPath $coreTown");
```

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
InFile="./zipcode.txt"
"$Work1"="$1"
"$OutFile"="$2"
"$InString"="$3"

echo "$1";
echo "$2";
echo "$3";
```

Returned by the 'echo' in the script:

```
WorkString531cdf6b8b3451.99781853 OutString531cdf6b8b3451.99781853 Houston,
```

Notice the state (TX) is missing. If I put 'echo "$4";' in there it will display the 'TX'. 
Is one of these languages handling the content of 'coreTown' ('Houston, TX') as an array? If so, which one? Amd how do I fix it? My google searches did not address this problem.

Comment: The lines like `"$Work1"="$1"` don't make sense. It should be `Work1=$1`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `$coreTown` contains a space, that's being treated as an argument delimiter in the shell; you need to quote it or escape the space. Luckily, PHP has a function that does that for you: [`escapeshellarg`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php).

```
$workPathEsc = escapeshellarg($workPath);
$outPathEsc = escapeshellarg($outPath);
$coreTownEsc = escapeshellarg($coreTown);
$errorTap = shell_exec("./Find-Town.sh $workPathEsc $outPathEsc $coreTownEsc");
```